# Можно ли как то упростить проверки

Tags: php

```
     if(!is_array($pgrPhy)){
       terminate("Please chose physician in Product Interest section" . $item->Pgr_Id);
       if (!array_key_exist($item->Pgr_Id,$pgrPhy)) {
                            terminate("Please chose physician in Product Interest section" . $item->Pgr_Id);
                            if (!$pgrPhy[$item->Pgr_Id]) {
                                terminate("Please chose physician in Product Interest section" . $item->Pgr_Id);
                            }
                        }
    }
```

Упрощу
$pgrPhy = getPhy() из $_POST

```
         if(!is_array($pgrPhy)){
//Откатить транзакцию
         if (!array_key_exist($item->Pgr_Id,$pgrPhy)) {
//Откатить транзакцию
         if (!$pgrPhy[$item->Pgr_Id]) {
//Откатить транзакцию
         }
         }
         }
```

Comment: соберите условия через или

Comment: Вам точно надо до трёх terminate? Т.е. нарушено одно условие - один раз terminate. Нарушено три условия - трижды terminate? Допустим этот terminate выдаёт сообщение пользователю. Тогда пользователь может получить одно, два или три одинаковых сообщения?

Comment: это как return false, код дальше не выполняется

Comment: Если код дальше первого terminate не выполняется, то что делает if после него? Вот и уберите проверки, которые в принципе никогда не выполняются. Или, если они должны выполняться, исправьте ошибки в программе, чтобы заработало. И только потом думайте об упрощении.

Comment: @Sergey Если не проверить что данные массив будет ошибка, если не проверить существует такой ключ будет ошибка, если не проверить есть ли значение у массива с заданным ключём будет ошибка.
Суть в том что если ошибка то нужно откатывать транзакцию, это и делает терминате, если ее убрать код будет выполнятся дальше следовательно будет ошибка. тоесть если оставить только один выход то будет как минимум 2 ошибки

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос для понимания контекста.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich три раза что ли отменить одну и туже транзакцию? Как только программа попадёт в первый if она откатит транзакцию, потом выполнит вложенный if (второй) и если он покажет истину, то откатит транзакцию второй раз и так далее. Это как-то необычно (как и с тремя сообщениями пользователю). Люди сбиты с толку и не знают что Вам посоветовать. Вы действительно именно этого хотите? Если нужно откатить транзакцию один раз при выполнении одного из условий, то правильный ответ в первом комментарии splash58.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Ваш код либо уже прост проще некуда, либо совершенно не правильный и упрощать смысла нет, надо для начала исправить.